# Post-processing after Popover completes?

Tags: ios, xcode, segue, popover

I have an IBAction method responding to a button press in my VC. This is wired (via Storyboard) to a Popover Segue.

I want to perform some processing specifically after the Popover has completed but if I put that code in the IBAction method, it is executed before the Popover.

Any pointers on how to do this (other than putting it in the Popover itself which, for reasons I won't go into here, is not an option)?

Thanks
Tony.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign a [UIPopoverDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html) (and [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverControllerDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009307)) to get notification of the close event